# Many nested `for` cycles depending on a variable

Tags: ruby, recursion, nested-loops

I want to put as many `for` cycles in themselfs depending of value in a variable.
For example, if the variable `@var = 1`, I need to perform:

```
for letter1 in @range
  do something
end
```

If the variable `@var = 2`:

```
for letter1 in @range
  for letter2 in @range
    do something
  end
end
```

If the variable @var = 3

```
for letter1 in @range
  for letter2 in @range
    for letter3 in @range
      do something
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a smarter/less code way than this code below? I don't wanna repeat myself all over again.

```
if @var == 1
  for letter2 in @range
    do something
  end
elsif @var == 2
  for letter1 in @range
    for letter2 in @range
      do something
    end
  end
elsif @var == 3
  for letter1 in @range
    for letter2 in @range
      for letter3 in @range
        do something
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

That `do something` part is always the same in each case. The difference is only how much cycles it is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about recursion: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)
It is something like:

```
def f(depth,letters=[])
  if depth == 0
    do someting with letters
  else
    for letter in @range
      f(depth-1,letters+[letter])
    end
  end
end

f(@var)
```

`f` is a function, which goes through letter calling itself again recursively. Each call have info `depth`, which means, how more deep recursion should be.

Comment: I theoreticaly know what recursion is, but I need to use those cycle variables (letter1, letter2, letter3 etc. from the code above) in that 'do something' part of the code. With this solution is there a way to do so? The script is contrusting all possible string combinations with @var length and the letters from @range. Thanks for an answer.

Comment: @Kreeki, `letters` is an array with letters - each of them was added to array by `+[letter]`. It makes new longer array and sends it to recursively called function.

Answer (score 1):

```
@range.map{|x| x}.product(*([@range.map{|x| x}] * n)) do |*args|
  do_something_with(*args)
end
```