# Variable count of 'for' cycles - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, loops, combinations

I want to put N for cycles in context:

```
for (NSInteger i=0; i<someCount; i++) {
    for(NSInteger j=i+1; j<someCount; j++){
       for(NSInteger z=j+1; z<someCount; z++){

       // my code here

       }
    }
}
```

I found the solution like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793090/many-nested-for-cycles-depending-on-a-variable), but don't understand how to transform it into Objective-C

Comment: Your question makes no sense. The posted code is Objective-C. What issue do you have with the posted code?

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert this code to use recursion? That is the technique used in the answer you linked. If so, what have you tried already?

Comment: I wrote something wrong may be, but it's not a solution yet. Yes, i need recursion, but how to rewrite it with Objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Is a substitute for recursion, hope it Helps:

First you need to make three new properties in your `@interface`

```
@property int a; //a variable for your loops do not edit its value other than what I say
@property int numberOfLoops;//the number of loops to nest inside each other
@property int someCount;//how many times each loop should repeat
```

Now in your `@implementation`:

```
-(void)repeatloops
{
for (int i = 0; i < self.someCount; i++){
if (self.a < self.numberOfLoops){
    self.a += 1;
    [self repeatloops];
}else{
    //do something for this loop, i'm gonna call this "sector a"
    //this would be the code you want to put inside each 'for' statement
}
}
self.a -= 1;
}
```

Now to call the loops:

```
self.a = 0; //don't forget this
self.numberOfLoops = N; //N was your example variable, don't forget to change this
self.someCount = X;//X is also an example variable, you can change it to a constant etc.
[self repeatloops];//call the method
```

This makes something loop exponentially. eg:
`self.numberOfLoops = 5`, `self.someCount = 1`,
`NSLog("a"); in "sector a"`   -> The result is (`self.numberOfLoops`^`self.someCount`)-- That many "a"s in your log window, don't make `self.someCount` to big!!

Comment: @АндрейБронников -No Problem!

Comment: "Note: in my code _ represents self. no need to replace though, it works anyway" - the two are not the same thing at all. The use of `_property` rather than `self.property` bypasses the settler/getter and breaks KVO. If something is not a property but just a variable you'd be better of using an instance variable... but then you are passing arguments (`N`, `X`) to `repeatLoops` via instance variables... But you did figure out what the question was, which I did not, well done!

Answer (score 0):

**Guess** - but maybe it will help.

In the title you write:

> Variable count

then in the question:

> I want to put N for cycles in context

and finally write the code:

> ```
> for (NSInteger i=0; i<someCount; i++)
> ```

Are you maybe asking about the use of literal values vs. variables in `for` loop conditions?

The code fragment:

```
i < someCount
```

is an *expression* which is evaluated before every iteration to the loop to determine whether the iteration should take place. It is not "pre-evaluated" in any way before the loop as a whole is executed.

If you write:

```
i < 42
```

then the condition will always test for the current value of `i` being less than `42` and execute an iteration if so. So the limit is a *constant*. You can also write something like:

```
i < j
```

then the limit is a *variable* - one possible interpretation of your question. The condition will evaluate whether the current value of `i` is less than the *current value* of `j`.

However ff the value of `j` changes during an iteration then the value that is used in the condition also changes - you have a "variable" limit - a different possible interpretation of your question, in this case rather than the limit being obtained from a variable - as in the programming language construct - the limit itself *is* variable - as in it changes. This is valid as well, though you have to be careful that the loop terminates, e.g.:

```
NSInteger j = 1;
for( NSInteger i = 0; i < j, i++)
{
   j++;
}
```

will keep going (until overflow and wrap around occurs anyway!).

HTH